# What is best choice among "sake", "good", "benefit" and "interest"?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. I am saying this all for your sake.
> 2. I am saying this all for your own good.
> 3. I am saying this all for your benefit.
> 4. I am saying this all for your interest.

When talking and reasoning with a kid, which sentences above are correct and which one is most common and natural?

Comment: Parents usually interchange any/all of the first 3; saves the child getting bored with the same old reason ;-) I wouldn't use 4, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them sound natural to me because they use "this all", instead of "all this". If you said a lot of things, "all this", if you said one thing, "this".

> I am saying (all) this for your own good.

Yes.

> I am saying (all) this for your interest.

No, this stands out as saying something different. Is the kid interested? Probably not. "I am saying (all) this *in your best interest*" fits better.

These two sound more encouraging; "I know you might not enjoy hearing this, but you need to hear it".

> I am saying all this for your benefit.
>
> I am saying all this for your sake.

These are clear.

These two sound more annoyed and reproachful; "stop ignoring me and *listen*, this is for YOUR benefit not MINE".

Comment: When you mentioned "'These two", does it always refer to  two sentences ABOVE?

Comment: Not always. I intended it to refer to the two sentences above, but I was not very clear. It could be used to introduce two new sentences below, e.g. *"Sentence 1 and 2 are clear. These two: {...}  are not*"